# Unknown class <class_name> in Interface Builder file - IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have fixed this issue by adding the following lines...

```
[<class_name> class];
```

in application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in Appdelegate. I got this idea while checking for solution in one of the thread in SO. Can anyone explain what was the problem? I have customized the tableview cell by adding xib and its corresponding .h and .m, when I tried to load like this...

```
          if (cell == nil)
            {
                NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"<class_name>" owner:self options:nil];
                cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
            }
```

application crashed with the above mentioned error.

thanks

Comment: What is the class name of acustomized tableview cell ? <class_name> ?

Comment: Its my new class name for the UITableViewCell

Comment: Means I'm asking what is the class name of that custom table view cell, the .h and .m file name for the custom tableviewcell. It can't be UITableViewCell. It's a built in class.

Comment: Ya the same name whatever I give for nib I have used it in .h and .m, not UITableViewCell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't name a xib / nib file "`<class_name>`".  Just don't.

Name it something that makes more sense in terms of Objective C, e.g. "`NewbeeTableViewCell`".

Also, in the xib file, make certain that it contains your custom table view cell.  Go into the Identity Inspector for that table view cell and change the name of the cell from "`UITableViewCell`" to "`NewbeeTableViewCell`" or whatever name you want your subclassed table view cell to be.  This is what was causing the "Unknown class" error you were seeing while building.